# Calculate $\lim_{a \to 0}\frac{2^n-(2-a)(2-2^2a)(2-3^2a).....(2-n^2a)}{2^na}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, partial-derivative, roots

I have tried every way I know to calculate this end (divide $a^n$, divide $2^n$, derivation) but without any result.

Can you help me calculate it? and thank you very much.

$$
\lim_{a \to 0}\frac{2^n-(2-a)(2-2^2a)(2-3^2a).....(2-n^2a)}{2^na}
$$

[I could not find a solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arTv9.png)

Comment: The pic you shared already has a very good solution to the problem. What problem are you facing in that?

Comment: Agreed with @AnkitKumar. I found a solution on the picture **you** posted. I'm not sure why you didn't find it.

Comment: Why did you delete the previous question and repost it unmodified at about the same time?

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is that I do not know how to prove the following equal $$\lim_{a \to 0} \frac{1}{a}[1-\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1-\frac{k^2}{2}a)]=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^2}{2}$$

Comment: I deleted the previous publication because it is old and nobody is interested in it. Please help me and thank you

Answer (score 2):

For fixed $n$, the expression in the numerator is a polynomial $f(a)=c_0+c_1a+c_2a^2+\ldots$ in $a$ (apparently of degree $\deg f=n$, so we stop at $c_na^n$).
By plugging in $a=0$, we immediate see that $c_0=f(0)=2^n-(2-0)\cdots(2-0)=0$.
Then it readily follows that 
$$ \lim_{a\to0}\frac{f(a)}{2^na}=\lim_{a\to0}\frac{c_1+c_2a+\ldots+c_na^{n-1}}{2^n}=\frac{c_1}{2^n}.$$
Thus we need the linear term of $f(a)$, or equivalently, the negative linear term of the product $(2-a)(2-2^2a)\cdots(2-n^2a)$.
Note that for two polynomials $g(X)=g_0+g_1X+\ldots$ and $h(X)=h_0+h_1X+\ldots$, we have $$\tag1g(X)h(X)=g_0h_0+(g_0h_1+g_1h_0)X+\ldots$$ and this allows us to compute the linear and constant term of a product from only the linear and constant temrs of the factors.
Letting $g_n(X)=(1-\frac12X)(1-\frac {2^2}2X)\cdots(1-\frac{n^2}2X)$, we have the recursion $g_n(X)=g_{n-1}(X)\cdot(1-\frac{n^2}2X)$. As clearly the constant term of $g_n$ is $1$, we find from $(1)$ the following recursion for the linear coefficient $g_{n,1}$ of $g_n(X)$:
$$ g_{n,1}=g_{n-1,1}-\frac{n^2}2$$
with the initial condition $g_{0,1}=0$. Quite obviously, thius makes $$g_{n,1}=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}.$$
Now as $f(X)=2^n-2^ng(X)$, we conclude 
$$\lim_{a\to0}\frac{f(a)}{2^na}=\frac{c_1}{2^n}=-g_{n,1}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}. $$

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me.